# ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid

Tags: oracle

O que significa este erro?

Quais as ações que podem ser tomadas para remediá-lo?

Comment: Como não há quem responda veja este [artigo](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00980_synonym_translation_is_no_longer_valid.htm)

Comment: @ramaral Não abre aqui pra mim. Fiz a pergunta porque nenhum dos artigos que pesquisei me dá uma resposta objetiva.

Comment: O que quer dizer com "Não abre aqui pra mim."?

Comment: @ramaral O site não abre. Diz que o endereço está indisponível.

Comment: O link está correto. Eu clico em [artigo](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00980_synonym_translation_is_no_longer_valid.htm) no meu comentário e abre.

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00980_synonym_translation_is_no_longer_valid.htm

Comment: Será que vocês poderiam, se não for pedir muito, **responder à pergunta em português**? Se eu quisesse a resposta do Google em inglês não teria vindo aqui.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tradução livre da [documentação oficial](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/e900.htm#ORA-00980)

#### ORA-00980: A tradução do sinônimo não é mais válida

**Causa:** Um sinônimo não foi traduzido para um objeto de destino legal. Isso pode ocorrer por uma das seguintes razões:

1. O esquema de destino não existe.
2. O objeto de destino não existe.
3. O sinônimo especifica um link de banco de dados (*database link*) incorreto.
4. O sinônimo não é versionado mas específica um objeto de destino versionado.

**Ação:** Mude a definição do sinônimo para que o sinônimo aponte para um objeto de destino legal.

---

Trocando em miúdos, alguém mexeu no objeto de destino (ou até mesmo no *SCHEMA*, *db link*, etc) e esqueceu de recriar / excluir o sinônimo.